# Populate select box with key:value pair?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery and have server code returning the following values

```
0:SELECT ONE;1:VALUE1;2:VALUE2 etc
```

How do I populate this into a select box?

```
var="0:SELECT ONE;1:VALUE1;2:VALUE2";
$("#targetSelectBox"). ???????
```

Comment: Please do not tag a javascript question with java.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var opts = "0:SELECT ONE;1:VALUE1;2:VALUE2";
opts = opts.split(';');
var target = $("#targetSelectBox");
$.each(opts, function(i, opt){
  opt = opt.split(':');
  target.append($('<option />').val(opt[0].trim()).text(opt[1].trim()));
});
```

Comment: Should be $('<option/>') to create a new element. Otherwise you're updating the value and text of all <option> elements on the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use jquery's [add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) function.

For e.g.

```
var options = ["0":{"description":"Select an item"}, "1":{"description":"item 1"}];
var dropdown =  $("#dropdown_id")[0];
$.each(options, function(i, item) {
    var option = new Option(item.description, i);
    if ($.browser.msie) {
        dropdown.add(option);
    }
    else {
        dropdown.add(option, null);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Variable holding key-value pairs
var values = "1:VALUE;2:VALUE";
// Convert to an array of key-values
var vals   = values.split(";");
// Cycle through each pair
for (var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
  // Split to get true key, and true value
  var parts = vals[i].split(":");
  // Append new option holding true key, and true value
  $("#targetSelectBox").append($("option").val(parts[0]).text(parts[1]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine in firefox but not in IE. I get "Object doesn't support property or method". Therefore I propose this solution:

```
var target = $("#targetSelectBox")
var vals   = values.split(";");
for (var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
  var parts = vals[i].split(":");
  target.append($('<option />').val(parts[0].trim()).text(parts[1].trim()));
}
```