# jquery append not working in IE works fine in FF

Tags: javascript, string, internet-explorer, firefox, trim

this code works fine in FF, not in IE.

```
var target = $("#targetSelectBox")
var vals   = values.split(";");
for (var i = 0; i < vals.length; i++) {
        var parts = vals[i].split(":");
 target.append($('<option />').val(parts[0].trim()).text(parts[1].trim()));
}
```

Comment: Why did you accept an answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111859/jquery-populate-select-box-with-keyvalue-pair) if the solution didn't work?

Comment: worked fine with firefox, when i tried in IE it did not work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a semi-colon after the first line:

```
var target = $("#targetSelectBox")//;
```

Be sure that this selector is actually finding your element:

```
<select id="targetSelectBox">
  <!-- options to come -->
</select>
```

We'll also need to see the full portion of your code, including what `values` is to begin with. Additionally, make sure that jQuery is properly referenced, and you might even consider wrapper your inner `target` reference in the jQuery wrapper as well:

```
var newOption = $("<option>").val( parts[0] ).text( parts[1] );
$(target).append(newOption);
```

**Functional example online:** http://jsbin.com/ibeci/edit

Comment: @shah-bc: See my functional example link a the bottom of my post.

Comment: Firefox provides a String.trim() method in its javascript while IE does not.